# Scheduler Expression

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

How can I write an Quartz Scheduler Expression to create a trigger that fires every 5 minutes between 15:30 and 15:55 in one simple expression case? Is that possible? or should I create more than one trigger, and register both of them to run the same job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the easiest (but not necessarily most elegant) way to achieve this:

```
0 30,35,40,45,50,55 15 * * ?
```